# Logging Apache2 payload to evaluate SOAP message

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, soap, payload

I am trying to log webservice specific information with Apache (Apache acts as a load-balancer by use of mod_jk). For instance I want to know how long the responsetime of each webservice-call takes. To do this I definitely would need to know the name of the webservice-method in the log-file.
As a matter of fact, the name of the webservice-method is wrapped in the SOAP-body, to which I have no access to with the default-configuration.

Does anybody know an Apache module to extend the log-information? Or are there any other ideas to solve this challenge?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Most service frameworks and hybrid frameworks offer methods for calculating load and event logging.

You could opt for service implementation in **CXF**.
or more lighter under **Axis** implementation.

There are some projects of Apache loggin that could solve your problem this is the link:

[Apache logging services](http://logging.apache.org/)

> *I personally think that the lightest solution would be to develop a small module apache to identify specific traffic and
>   avoid overload of data processing by additional service*

Comment: As I am interestet not only in information a framework could give me but in application-specific data, I definitely will consider your suggestion in writing my own apache-module. Thanks for your input!